# Sequelize: include child if parent attribute is equals to specific value

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using nodejs v8.9.0 + expressjs v4.14.0 + sequelize v3.25.0 to build a web app in which people can ask questions each others. A user can ask a public or a private(for specifics users) question

Here is the user model:

```
/** USER MODEL **/
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var User = sequelize.define('users', {
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        field: 'firstName' 
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        field: 'lastName' 
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        field: 'email'
    },
},
{
    classMethods: {
        User.belongsToMany(
            models.questions, 
            {
                through: 'QuestionRecipient',  foreignKey: 'userId'
            }
        );
    }
})
```

Here is the question model:

```
/** QUESTION MODEL **/
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var Question = sequelize.define('questions', {
    content: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        field: 'content' 
    },
    target: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'target',
        defaultValue: 1 // 1 = public / 2 = private
    }
},
{
    classMethods: {
        Question.belongsToMany(
            models.users, 
            {
                through: 'QuestionRecipient',  foreignKey: 'questionId'
            }
        );
    }
})
```

Now when I'm querying questions, I want to include users through 'QuestionRecipient' only if question.target = 2 which means the question is for specifics users

How to do this query ?

Thanks

Comment: So you only want to include users if the target is 2? Or only retrieve questions that have the target 2, and include users in that?

Comment: @MichaelMcCabe only include users if target is 2, which means the question is not public but for specifics users